# email not getting sent in rails 4 using sidekiq

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to send an email in rails 4 using sidekiq.
In this the values are not getting saved in the database instead only the form values are taken and the email is sent.
I have follwed this link https://www.codefellows.org/blog/how-to-set-up-a-rails-4-2-mailer-with-sidekiq

But the problem is that the email is not getting sent.

visitor_controller.rb

```
class VisitorsController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end

    def contact
        h = JSON.generate({ 'name' => params[:name],
                            'email' => params[:email],
                            'message' => params[:message] })

       PostmanWorker.perform_async(h, 5)

        # if instead of sidekiq I was just sending email from rails
         #VisitorMailer.contact_email(@name, @email, @message).deliver

        redirect_to :root
    end
end
```

visitor_mailer.rb

```
class VisitorMailer < ApplicationMailer
    def contact_email(name, email, message)
    @name = name
    @email = email
    @message = message
    mail(from: @email,
        to: 'javier@badaboom.com',
         subject: 'New Visitor\'s Email')
  end
end
```

contact_email.html.erb

```
<html>
   <head>
     <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
   </head>
   <body>
     <h1><%= @name %> (<%= @email %>)</h1>
     <p>
       <%= @message %>
     </p>
   </body>
 </html>
```

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Email</h1> 

<p>
    <%= label_tag(:name, "My name is:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:name) %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= label_tag(:email, "My email address is:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:email) %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= label_tag(:message, "My Message is:") %>
    <%= text_area_tag(:message) %>
</p>


<p>
    <%= submit_tag("Send Email") %>
</p>
```

I want to as to why the email is not getting sent...
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Did you complete all the steps in the article? You need a background worker and Sidekiq also needs to be running (`bundle exec sidekiq`).

Comment: I have created a worker Postman   Here is the code:  postman_worker.rb   class PostmanWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(h, count)
    h = JSON.load(h)
    VisitorMailer.contact_email(h['name'], h['email'], h['message']).deliver
  end
end

Comment: A background worker is a server process. This is different than your PostmanWorker class. It sounds like you don't have sidekiq running, but you can narrow the range of possibilities by trying to send the email inline, rather than through a worker. If you can send the email inline, then you know it's a problem with your worker.